# How to link a subfolder with gcc in C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, subdirectory

I have the below tree:

```
├── cminpack
│   ├── hybrd.c
│   ├── hybrd.o
│   ├── hybrj1.c
│   ├── hybrj1.o
│   ├── hybrj.c
│   ├── hybrj.o
│   ├── libminpack.a
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── minpack.h
│   ├── minpack.h.gch
│   ├── readmeC.txt
│   ├── readme.txt
├── greeter.c
├── greeter.h
├── greeter.o
├── swaps.c
├── swaps.h
├── swaps.o
```

The files:

- `cminpack` is a package I found and copied and I can `make` it successfully
- `swaps.c` is where my `main` is, I also do have the below in it:

```
#include "./cminpack/minpack.h"
#include "./greeter.h"
```

- `greeter.c` is another file with some functions

In `swaps.c` I call a function from `greeter.c` and function `hybrd_` from `cminpack/hybrd.c`. I want to link both `greeter` and `cminpack` to my `swaps`.

I manage to link `greeter` by running the below gcc command:

`sudo gcc -c swaps.c greeter.c ;sudo gcc -o swaps swaps.c greeter.c -lm ;./swaps`

Now if I try to link `cminpack` I am running the below gcc command:

`sudo gcc -c swaps.c greeter.c -I./cminpack;sudo gcc -o swaps swaps.c greeter.c -lm -L /cminpack`

This leads to the infamous linking error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxwxt6A.o: in function `fsolve':
swaps.c:(.text+0xfb3): undefined reference to `hybrd_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I link the subfolder?

(gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6))

Comment: Don’t run everything with `sudo`.  Only installation might require root privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `-L cminpack`, you should add `-lminpack` to the `gcc` command line.

There should be no reason to use `sudo` for the compilation of this program, if you cannot invoke `gcc` directly, your system is misconfigured and should be fixed. Running the compiler as root is highly discouraged.

Create a `Makefile` in the main directory with these lines:

```Makefile
%.o: %.c greeter.h swaps.h cminpack/minpack.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -I cminpack -o $@ $*.c

swap: swap.o greeter.o cminpack/libminpack.a
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ swaps.o greeter.o -L cminpack -lminpack -lm

cminpack/libminpack.a:
    make -C cminpack
```

Comment: Thank you adding `-lminpack` did it. I remember trying that and it told be there was no package named minpack but somehow I must have done something and it works fine thanks. Duly noted for the use of `sudo`. And I will look in creating a makefile.

Comment: @BagourdArthur: You need both options: `-lminpack` means look for a library named **libminpack.a** or **libminpack.so** and `-L cminpack` adds the `cminpack` directory to the places where the linker searches for libraries. Alternately, you could just specify `cminpack/libminpack.a` on the command line and all modules from this library would be unconditionally statically linked to the executable.